# Passing Byte (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, byte, encode

I need to pass encoded string to php page.

To convert string to iso:

```
Dim result As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), input)
```

I have this code to pass string, but how I must do it to pass Byte (variable result) instead of the string (variable MyVarString)?

```
Dim client As WebClient
Dim data As Stream
Dim reader As StreamReader
Dim baseurl As String
baseurl = "http://example.com/api/mypage2.php"
client = New WebClient
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
client.QueryString.Add("mensaje", MyVarString)
data = client.OpenRead(baseurl)
reader = New StreamReader(data)
s = reader.ReadToEnd()
data.Close()
reader.Close()
Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to pass a byte array then just Base64 encode it:

```
Dim encResult = Convert.ToBase64String(result)
```

Then in PHP use the [built-in decoder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) `base64_decode(string)`